# Detecting drag position on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-email, wysiwyg

I am building a wysiwyg editor to build html emails. I want to be able to add row layouts to the editor by drag and drop.

If a row is dragged and dropped above the halfway point of the drop target, I want to prepend a row before the drop target; and if it is dropped below the halfway point, I want to append a row after the drop target.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What did you try yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get coordinates of the element while mouse button pressed and moving simply like this

```
element.onClick = function() {
    element.onmousemove = function() {
        var x1 = element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            x2 = x1 + element.getBoundingClientRect().width,
            y1 = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
            y2 = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
}
```

and now you can do whatever you would like with these coordinates.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. I haven't finished my solution yet, but this looks like it'll work!

Comment: y2 = y1 + element.getBoundingClientRect().height